# Is there anything to be said about this matrix product. Tensor product.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tensor-products, products

Given a matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, such that $\min\{\mathcal{R}(\lambda_i):\lambda_i~\text{is an eigenvalue of $A$}~\}>0$ is non-defective. Let $z_i$ be the (column) eigenvectors of $A$, and define

$$Z:=\begin{pmatrix}z_1&\ldots&z_n\end{pmatrix}.$$

What properties/can we say anything obvious about the product $$A^{-1}ZZ^T$$
have? Note that $AZ=\Lambda Z$ where $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix of corresponding eigenvalues.

---

Note $^T$ denotes transpose and $\mathcal{R}(\cdot)$ returns the real part of a complex number.

Comment: "non-defective" means that has multiplicity $1$ as a zero of the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: non-defective means : algebraic multiplicity = geomoetric multiplicity

Comment: if either the matrix is singular or there are eigen-values with zero real part the product $A^{-1}ZZ^{\top}$ isn't exists

Comment: By assumption all eigenvalues of $A$ have positive real part.

Comment: a little probe with some instances, $ZZ^{\top}$ always gives a diagonal matrix ${\rm diag}[-2,2,-2,2,...,-2,2, d_1,...,d_r]$, the $\pm2$ for the complex eigenvalues and the $d_i$ for the real ones, even in cases where eigenvalues have zero or negative parts and higher multiplicities